# ¿Cómo crear estructura repetitiva con arreglos en C?

Tags: c

Me han pedido en el colegio una actividad que resuelva el problema siguiente:

Calcular la calificación final de un alumno de la Licenciatura en Desarrollo de Software, solicitando :

- nombre del alumno.
- nombre de las materias
- calificación de cada una de ellas

Lo he hecho de la siguiente manera y solo usando 4 materias y en teoría esta correcto, pero acepta cualquier carácter como calificación, entonces debo corregirlo para que solo acepte números en un rango del 0 al 10, me he llevado toda la tarde haciéndolo y ya me siento un poco frustrado, agradecería sus consejos para mejorar mi código y entregar mi actividad. Les agradezco su ayuda.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct datos{
char nombre[30];
float calif;
}materias[4];

int main()
{
float suma, prome;
char Nom1[30];
int i,j;

printf("Ingresa el nombre completo del alumno:\n");
fgets(Nom1, 30, stdin);
        
for(i=0;i<4;i++){
    printf("Ingresa el nombre de la asignatura #%d:\n",(i+1));
    scanf("%s", &materias[i].nombre);
    printf("Ingresa la calificacion de %s:\n", materias[i].nombre);
    scanf("%f", &materias[i].calif);
    fflush(stdin);
    suma=suma+materias[i].calif;
}
prome = ((suma)/4);
system("cls");

printf("Nombre del Alumno: %s\n", Nom1);
printf("Promedio: %.2f \n", prome);

for(i=0;i<4;i++){
    printf("Materia %s : %.2f \n", materias[i].nombre, materias[i].calif);
}
system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: Entiendo que tu problema concreto es: tienes que repetir la introducción de la calificación hasta que sea un valor permitido. ¿ Correcto ?

Comment: ¡Si!, esa es la situación.

Answer (score 0):

> pero acepta cualquier carácter como calificación, entonces debo corregirlo para que solo acepte números en un rango del 0 al 10

Yo pase por un problema similar. [Aqui esta la pregunta que hice en el sitio en ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59490196/while-using-scanfi-var-if-the-user-enters-a-letter-or-just-presses-enter-i). Leer los comentarios que me colocaron puede que te sea de ayuda.

En resumen, usar `scanf` para leer la entrada del usuario es una muy mala idea. Es muy inseguro, y deja "sucio" el stream.

Lo que yo encontre como solucion a base de los comentarios es leer primero como string la entrada, y luego procesarla para confirmar que sea correcta.

Si quieres intentarlo por tu cuenta primero, te recomiendo que busques en cppreference:

- `fgets`
- `sscanf`

La solucion a la que llegue es la siguiente:

```
// -2147483648 es lo mas largo en texto que se puede poner un `int`
#define INT_STRING_SIZE 12


char variable[INT_STRING_SIZE]; 
int var;
do {
    printf("Please write an integer: ");
    fgets(variable, INT_STRING_SIZE, stdint);
} while(sscanf(variable, "%i", &var) != 1 );
```

Aqui si se verifica la entrada, y tienes la ventaja de que no pierdes lo que ingreso el usuario en caso de que aun creas que puedes hacer algo con ella (Como mostrar un mensaje de error).

Ya de aqui solo verificas que el valor este entre 0 y 10, y listo.